# How can I limit the rotation of a 3D object when touch is used to rotate it?

Tags: c++, math

I'm working on a project where I have to show a 3D model of a few buildings and the user can pick one of them. They can rotate/move/scale the 3D model freely, but now I need to limit the those so they can't see under the model, scale too much or move the model away from the screen. The current code is a bit of a mystery since I didn't write it and the guy who did it is not being really helpful, so I decided to rewrite it.

This is the current rotation code:

```
void Building3DLayer::rotate(float x, float y)
{
    if(!active) return;
    kmMat4 copy, rot;

    x /= 100.f;
    y /= 100.f;

    kmMat4Assign(&copy, &_state.modelview);
    kmMat4RotationY(&rot, x);
    kmMat4Multiply(&_state.modelview, &copy, &rot);

    kmMat4Assign(&copy, &_state.modelview);
    _state.rX += y;
    kmVec3 axis = {copy.mat[0],copy.mat[4],copy.mat[8]};
    kmMat4RotationAxisAngle(&rot, &axis, y);

    kmMat4Multiply(&_state.modelview, &copy, &rot);

    kmMat4Multiply(&_mvp, &_projection, &_state.modelview);
}
```

What can I use to achieve something like that? I think I could just use a vec3 for position, one for rotation and a float for the building scale (instead of translating to zoom in/out), but I don't know how to change the limits based on the zoom (if you are close to it, you can drag the building more than you would be able to if you far from it). I also read about arcball rotations, are they easier to work with (and to add limits) than simple vectors (even if harder to write)?

Comment: Could you provide more details on the libraries being used? The code multiplies the modelview matrix twice, once with a rotation matrix that rotates by `x` around the y-axis and once by a rotation matrix that rotates by `y` around the first column of the (already updated) matrix. You may want to read up on axis-angle representation and Rodrigues' formular.

Comment: @MarkusMayr I'm using cocos2d-x and kazmath, and I really don't understand what's happening in the code I posted, it was just as an example of how it is being done right now. Is there anything more specific to look besides axis-angle representation?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't change the representation of the transformations. Matrices are the ideal choice for your scenario. Many other options are difficult to handle when chaining transformations. If you change existing code, you should be absolutely sure what you are doing. It is very likely that the previous programmer had his reasons to do it the way he did it.

### The idea

I assume that the above method is called subsequently with quite small parameters. Then you could do the following:

1. Save the old transformation
2. Modify the transformation
3. Project the modified object on the screen
4. Check, if the result matches your constraints
5. If not, revert the transformation to the previous one.

This should work if the parameters are small enough. Otherwise, you will have to break down the transformation into smaller steps.

### The constraints

The first constraint (the user must not look under the model) is pretty easy to achieve. You just have to determine if the model is completely in front of the z-near plane. You can approximate this by calculating the signed distance of the model's bounding sphere to the plane. You can also do this with a bounding box or even the whole model (although I would not recommend that).

The second one (the user must not move the model off the screen) can be achieved in a similar way. You will need the view frustum planes for that. Then there are several approaches. I would advice to always keep the model's center within the frustum (by calculating the signed distance to all planes). This way it is possible to move the model partly, but not entirely, off the screen which might be desirable. If you don't want this, Do a more restricting check (e.g. with the entire bounding volume).